# Tensorflow Custom layer weights not training but bias is

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I've been writing some custom layers and I have realized my bias values will train but my weights are not training.  I'm going to use a very simplified code here to illustrate the issue.

```
class myWeights(Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs): 
        self.units = units
        super(myWeights, self).__init__(**kwargs)      
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                         initializer='GlorotUniform',
                         trainable=True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),
                         initializer='random_normal',
                         trainable=True)
        super(myWeights, self).build(input_shape)
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return(input_shape[0],self.units)
```

Now I set up MNIST data to train.  I also set a seed so this is reproducible on your end.

```
tf.random.set_seed(1234)
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train=tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test=tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)
```

I build out the model using the functional API

```
inp=Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1:]))
flat=Flatten()(inp)
hid=myWeights(32)(flat)
out=Dense(10, 'softmax')(hid)
model=Model(inp,out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
         loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
         metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now when I check the values of the parameters using

```
print(model.layers[2].get_weights())
```

I see output like the following, which I have reformatted for easier reading.

> - [array([[ 0.00652369, -0.02321771,  0.01399945, ..., -0.07599965,
>         -0.04356881, -0.0333882 ],
>        [-0.03132245, -0.05264733,  0.05576386, ..., -0.03755575,
>          0.07358163, -0.02338506],
>        [-0.01808248,  0.04092623,  0.02177643, ...,  0.00971264,
>          0.07631209,  0.0495184 ],
>        ...,
>        [-0.03780914,  0.00219346,  0.04460619, ..., -0.06703794,
>          0.03407502, -0.01071112],
>        [-0.0012739 , -0.0683699 , -0.06152753, ...,  0.05373723,
>          0.03079057,  0.00855774],
>        [ 0.06245673, -0.07649396,  0.06748571, ..., -0.06948434,
>         -0.01416317, -0.08318184]], dtype=float32), *
> - array([ 0.05734033,  0.04822996,  0.04391507, -0.01550511,  0.05383257,
>         0.05043739, -0.04092903, -0.0081823 , -0.06425817,  0.02402171,
>        -0.00374672, -0.06069579, -0.08422226,  0.02909392, -0.02071654,
>         0.0422841 , -0.05020861,  0.01267704,  0.0365625 , -0.01743891,
>        -0.01030697,  0.00639807, -0.01493454,  0.03214667,  0.03262959,
>         0.07799669,  0.05789128,  0.01754347, -0.07558075,  0.0466203 ,
>        -0.05332188,  0.00270758], dtype=float32)]*

After training with

```
model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=3, verbose=1)
print(model.layers[2].get_weights())
```

I find the following output.

> - [array([[ 0.00652369, -0.02321771,  0.01399945, ..., -0.07599965,
>         -0.04356881, -0.0333882 ],
>        [-0.03132245, -0.05264733,  0.05576386, ..., -0.03755575,
>          0.07358163, -0.02338506],
>        [-0.01808248,  0.04092623,  0.02177643, ...,  0.00971264,
>          0.07631209,  0.0495184 ],
>        ...,
>        [-0.03780914,  0.00219346,  0.04460619, ..., -0.06703794,
>          0.03407502, -0.01071112],
>        [-0.0012739 , -0.0683699 , -0.06152753, ...,  0.05373723,
>          0.03079057,  0.00855774],
>        [ 0.06245673, -0.07649396,  0.06748571, ..., -0.06948434,
>         -0.01416317, -0.08318184]], dtype=float32), *
> - array([-0.250459  , -0.21746232,  0.01250297,  0.00065066, -0.09093136,
>         0.04943814, -0.13446714, -0.11985168,  0.23259214, -0.14288908,
>         0.03274751,  0.1462888 , -0.2206902 ,  0.14455307,  0.17767513,
>         0.11378342, -0.22250313,  0.11601174, -0.1855521 ,  0.0900097 ,
>         0.21218981, -0.03386492, -0.06818825,  0.34211585, -0.24891953,
>         0.08827516,  0.2806849 ,  0.07634751, -0.32905066, -0.1860122 ,
>         0.06170518, -0.20212872], dtype=float32)]*

I can see that the bias values have changed but the weight values are static.  I'm not sure at all why this is occurring.